# How can I use an already authenticated acess token to start SheetService so that I don't have to start a new authentication

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I already have an authenticated scope for google sheets in another layer of my application and would like to reuse this authentication without starting the SheetService object again, I would just pass the already authenticated token to the layer that will handle the spreadsheets.

I am using .Net Framework 4.5.2 and Google Sheets SDK which can be viewed at https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet

```cs
//The sample from Google:
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream =
                new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }
            // Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


//What I need

// Create Google Sheets API service.
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = **EXISTED_TOKEN**,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
```

Comment: If you have the credential stored/serialized to JSON and stored somewhere, can't you simply deserialize that into a UserCredential object and use that for HttpClientInitializer?

Comment: Pass the instance of the client to the other layers.

Comment: @Jon The idea is that the layer responsible for authentication is a DMZ (network zone without firewall), and the part that would use the authentication token is responsible for requests inside the firewall or something similar.